# Does having has_many and belongs_to using ActiveRecord generate alter sql statements in structure.sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have code like this

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

While creating generate migration, I didn't use any keyword to generate foreign key associations. But I see alter sql statement with respect to adding foreign key in structure.sql . How and Why?

Answer (score 3):

Merely setting up the associations in your model DOES NOT alter the schema in any way and this code will just give an undefined column error unless you actually create the books.author_id column through a migration.

Running the model generator with `author:belongs_to` or `author:references` (which are aliases) does add a foreign key column to the migration as well as a `belongs_to :author` association in the model.

```
# rails g model book title:string author:belongs_to
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.belongs_to :author, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But a association does not actually have to have a *foreign key constraint*. If you ran the generator with `author_id:bigint` the association will work but you will have no foreign key constraint to guarantee referential integrity.

Using `books:has_many` on the other hand in a generator will generate a bad migration since a `has_many` association is not a database column.

Comment: Got it. But if I have 
```class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
         create_table  :books do |t|
             t.integer :author_id //just because I have _id after author where author seems //to be another model, does it create a foreign key constraint?
         end
      end
  end```

Comment: No. That assumption is completely false. Rails does really care what you name your columns in this way and a migration knows nothing about the other tables in the database. This will just create a integer column. Its only if you use `t.belongs_to/references` or actually manually add a foreign_key with `add_foreign_key` that a constraint is added.